# Angular project migration issue with version 9 IVY compiler

Tags: angular, migration, angular9, angular-ivy

> I have migrated my angular project version 6 to 9 but till 8 my
> migration went smooth and it is working .once i migrate from v8 to v9
> my project gets blank on screen and the IVY does not showing any error
> on build and chrome console is also clear no error there too  i have
> tested with the test component and router-outlet is working but on my
> project component as the ivy compiles every piece of code at once so i
> am not able to get the affected area package or code to debug
>
> thanks in advance.

main.ts look like this

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

tsconfig.json

```
   {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json

```
  {
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.x.x",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.11.0",
    "angular-file-uploader": "^4.1.4",
    "angular-ng-autocomplete": "^1.1.17",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-haversine": "^0.1.1",
    "ng2-uploader": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^2.12.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^7.1.4",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^7.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.22",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some commas and post relevant code such as `package.json`, `tsconfig`, main module and the routing?

Comment: yes i have used all commas in router whenever i change the routing component to my newly created testcomponent .. routing works but my my project code redirect to path match does not work 
{ path: 'xx',  component: xx},

    { path: 'xx',  component: xx, canActivate: [WorkflowGuard] },

    { path: 'xx',  component: xx, canActivate: [WorkflowGuard] },

    { path: 'xx',  component: xx},
    { path: '',   redirectTo: '/xx', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/xx'}

Comment: I meant to use commas in your question. Also please add to your question the relative code formatted.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi please find above the releavant code

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and for me, it was a problem with Devextreme:

https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular/issues/975#issuecomment-580172291

> Starting with version 19.2.5 we support the IVY compiler.

---

I'd make sure that all your packages support IVY and upgrade accordingly.

Comment: No i am still facing issues with new IVY.
When i am running angular8 codebase with ng build/serve with --prod it works but on the angular 9 codebase only the ng server is running when i add the --prod on serve or build it does not work

Comment: i am always getting error on chrome 
polyfills.9b85908313a7766a001a.js:1 Unhandled Promise rejection: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded
 JIT compilation is discouraged for production use-cases! Consider AOT mode instead.
  - Did you bootstrap using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server'?
  - Alternatively provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded